# includes fail to include html.twig in template

Tags: drupal, twig

I am trying to create a drupal theme. I can't seem to use the {% include %} in the twig files. I do not know what is wrong? What do I need to add in the info.yml? or libraries.yml?

```
<header role="banner">
   {% include '@mytheme/includes/banner.html.twig'}
</header>
```

It prompts me:

> Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "@mytheme/includes/banner.html.twig" is not defined in "themes/custom/mytheme/template/page--front.html.twig" at line 49. in Twig\Loader\ChainLoader->getCacheKey() (line 98 of /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/ChainLoader.php).

Comment: Did you define the [namespace](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/components/registering-twig-namespaces)?

Comment: yes I tried installing the component module and add namespace

Comment: You don't need to add anything in `yourtheme.info.yml` or `yourtheme.libraries.yml`.   
As far as I can see there is a syntax error, but I think it is a typo. However, if we could see the complete code it would be better

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your template file to the Templates folder themes/THEMENAME/templates and change the path in the THEMENAME.layouts.yml

Also templates directory must always be a direct descendent of the module or theme root directory, in your case /modules/custom/MYMODULE/templates/ (not modules/custom/MYTHEME/includes/templates/).